# jQuery - (this).next going back to first

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to loop through 6 images on hover of an element, there is to be very little delay between changes and once it has got to the 6th image it needs to go back to the 1st, as soon as the user stops hovering, it should revert back to the first.

I have it partially working, it is cycling through the images but doesn't seem to be adding the delay and then after it gets to the 6th, all images disappear and it stops, also when I stop hovering it does not go back to the first.

Your help is greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

The CSS:

```
#map-container {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 750px;
                margin-top: 50px;
            }

            #map-container img {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .map-marker {
                position: absolute;
                float: left;
            }

            .map-marker img {
                width: 56px !important;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
            }

            .map-marker img.active {
                display: block;
            }

            .map-info-box {
                width: 350px;
                min-height: 100px;
                background: #f1f1f1;
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 50px;
                display: none;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .map-info-box h2 {
                display: block;
                background: #f65b2a;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 22px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 0px;
                line-height: 30px;
            }

            .map-info-box p {
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #838383;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            .map-info-box .findmore {
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                margin-left: 125px;
                background: #f65b2a;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 30px;
                color: white;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-top: 20px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            .map-info-box .findmore a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                display: block;
            }

            .map-marker:hover .map-info-box {
                display: block;
            }
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $(".map-marker").hover(function(){

                var i = 0;

                while (i < 1000){

                $('img.active').removeClass(function(){
                    $(this).next('img').addClass('active');
                    return 'active';
                })

                delay("300")

                i++;


                }

        });

        });
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="map-container">
            <img src="Map-of-UK.png" alt="UK Map" />

            <div class="map-marker" style="top: 600px; left: 300px;">
                <img src="m1.png" alt="marker" class="active" />
                <img src="m2.png" alt="marker" />
                <img src="m3.png" alt="marker" />
                <img src="m4.png" alt="marker" />
                <img src="m5.png" alt="marker" />
                <img src="m6.png" alt="marker" />

                <div class="map-info-box">
                    <h2>This is a test information box</h2>

                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>


                    <div class="findmore">
                        <a href="#">Find Out More</a>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `setInterval` to do this.

But first here the snippet for a *looping next*.

```
var $next = $(this).next('img');
if($next.length) $next.addClass('active');
else $(this).siblings().first().addClass('active');
```

For the interval, use somehting like this :

```
var timer;
$(".map-marker").hover(function(){

    timer = setInterval(function(){

        $('img.active').removeClass(function(){
            $(this).next('img').addClass('active');
            return 'active';
        });


    }.bind(this), 300);
}, function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works much better, although it doesn't hide the images after going to the next one therefore as the images are transparent backgrounds, it shows only the largest one and then doesn't return to the first after hover, is there a way around this?

Comment: @JamesLeist you could, when they are not `img.active`, set them on `display : none;` with CSS.